# How to run .net core 2 windows compiled NUnit test cases on Linux?

Tags: linux, nunit, .net-core-2.0

I have recently created a .Net Core 2 based project on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2017. I have two class library project, one is for source code and another project is for `NUnit` test cases of the source code. I built these projects using Visual Studio 2017 and I am able to run test cases using Test Explorer (After installing `NUnit` Adaptor `NuGet` package for my test project). 
Now, I want to test my source code on Linux so, I am finding a way to execute test cases on Linux. I don't want to build the project on Linux again.
Can anyone please let me know how to run NUnit test cases on Linux?
Can I copy generated DLLs in Linux machine?

Comment: I don't think that the `dotnet test` command will work on DLLs that you copied over, I think it needs a project. You could add an NUnitLite project that creates a self-executing test EXE that runs your test DLL.

Comment: `dotnet test` works on projects only, `dotnet vstest` is used for published test dll files

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a .NET Core test project, you can publish the test project and run the tests on a target system like this:

- Run `dotnet publish -o ..\tests` and copy the contents of the `..\tests` project to the target machine.
- Run `dotnet vstest yourtestproject.dll` on the machine to execute the tests.

Comment: Thanks Martin,
The command you mentioned seems to be working fine. I have one more question like what is recommended way?
Shall we publish the project in Windows OS and run on Linux?
Or shall we build separately on Linux OS and runt test cases there?

Comment: Technically it shouldn’t make a difference. Personally I like to ensure that projects build on all systems and I don‘t get any surprises later on, like windows-only exec steps in the build or things only working due to the case insensitive file system on windows. But it’s up to taste

Comment: Others may argue that the dll should only be built once and deployed and tested everywhere to protect against Compiler and build bugs. That is a valid argument as well (though I believe any compiler bug will be a pain in any setup)

Comment: Yes I agree with you. Thanks again for providing valuable inputs.